# ALTER COLUMN datatype to NOT NULL without dropping index and manually recreating it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-migration

I have a table with foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ForeignId] [int] NULL)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_OtherTable] FOREIGN KEY([ForeignId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[OtherTable] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExpedíciaVýrobky] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_OtherTable]

I would like to alter the ForeignId datatype to NOT NULL:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN ForeignId INT NOT NULL;
```

This requires to drop the FK contraint and recreate it.

Is it possible to do so without manually scripting ALTER TABLE CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY bla bla with all the details?

For example, if somebody edited the ON DELETE meanwhile, I don't wont to override this change.

EDIT:
In ideal world, I would like to have stored procedure `SpAlterColumnToNotNULL(tablename, columnname)`, that would do the dropping and recreating indexes automatically.

Comment: `This requires to drop the FK contraint and recreate it.` <-- you could change the nullability of the column without dropping the foreign key. Most likely there is an index on the ForeignId column which prohibits the column alteration. Just drop any index(es) and recreate them after altering the column.

Comment: Well, the same question remains with indexes :) Can I drop and recreate them without writing the script for creating index explicitly? Maybe there is a way to generate the script before droping index

Comment: Context is important. YOU don't have to write the scripts - SSMS can generate them for you if you ask it to. But there is no tool that will read your mind and do exactly what you want. You will need to understand the consequences of your actions and act accordingly. Now would be a good time to verify that all your code (including schema) is under proper source control and that you have a know, documented, and test disaster recovery plan.

Comment: I know I can generate the script in SSMS, but I would like to do it at runtime, if possible. If SSMS can generate it, at least theoretically it should be possible at runtime using T-SQL. BTW, I do have my migration scripts in git, but it will take at least a year or more until they go to production and production might diverse until then, since it is actively being upgraded in separate branch :/